# Pandas dataframe to excel: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a pandas dataframe, where I take an excel file, group for the maximum date in one column by the client ID in another. I want to save that as an excel file, so that I can check my work and make sure my output is what I want.

My code is as follows:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('ClientTrackExport.xlsx') 
grouped = [df1.groupby('ClientID')['BeginDate'].last()]
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('examples.xlsx') 
grouped.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet 1', index=False) 
writer.save()
```

And I get this error message:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

I followed the Pandas documentation to the letter, so I'm stuck. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

This comment from @roganjosh did the trick:

> No, it's the `[` and `]` on either end of that line. That makes it a single-element list. `df1.groupby('ClientID')['BeginDate'].last()` will give you the dataframe

Once I took away the brackets, everything worked as intended.